# Hive: apply lowercase to an array

Tags: java, arrays, string, hive, lowercase

In Hive, how do I apply the lower() UDF to an Array of string?
Or any UDF in general. I don't know how to apply a "map" in a select query

Comment: Are you trying to manipulate the result of a `collect_list`/`collect_set`, or is your use case more like you have arrays in a table that you need to transform?

Comment: getting an array from xml because of xpath... I need to make sure it's all lowercase

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - I added another scenario to the front of my answer which may be relevant to your situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your use case is that you are transforming an array in isolation (not as part of a table), then the combination of `explode`, `lower`, and `collect_list` should do the trick.  For example (please pardon the horrible execution times, I'm running on an underpowered VM):

```
hive> SELECT collect_list(lower(val))
    > FROM (SELECT explode(array('AN', 'EXAMPLE', 'ARRAY')) AS val) t;
...
... Lots of MapReduce spam
...
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 4 seconds 10 msec
Ended Job = job_1422453239049_0017
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Job 0: Map: 1  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 4.01 sec   HDFS Read: 283 HDFS Write: 17 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 4 seconds 10 msec
OK
["an","example","array"]
Time taken: 33.05 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

(Note:  Replace `array('AN', 'EXAMPLE', 'ARRAY')` in the above query with whichever expression you are using to generate the array.

If instead your use case is such that your arrays stored in a column of a Hive table and you need to apply the lowercase transformation to them, to my knowledge you have two principle options:

Approach #1:  Use the combination of `explode` and `LATERAL VIEW` to separate the array.  Use `lower` to transform the individual elements, and then `collect_list` to glue them back together.  A simple example with silly made-up data:

```
hive> DESCRIBE foo;
OK
id                          int                                 
data                        array<string>                       
Time taken: 0.774 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
hive> SELECT * FROM foo;
OK
1001        ["ONE","TWO","THREE"]
1002        ["FOUR","FIVE","SIX","SEVEN"]
Time taken: 0.434 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)

hive> SELECT
    >   id, collect_list(lower(exploded))
    > FROM
    >   foo LATERAL VIEW explode(data) exploded_table AS exploded
    > GROUP BY id;
...
... Lots of MapReduce spam
...
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 3 seconds 310 msec
Ended Job = job_1422453239049_0014
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Job 0: Map: 1  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 3.31 sec   HDFS Read: 358 HDFS Write: 44 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 3 seconds 310 msec
OK
1001        ["one","two","three"]
1002        ["four","five","six","seven"]
Time taken: 34.268 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

Approach #2:  Write a simple UDF to apply the transformation.  Something like:

```
package my.package_name;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;

public class LowerArray extends UDF {
  public List<Text> evaluate(List<Text> input) {
    List<Text> output = new ArrayList<Text>();
    for (Text element : input) {
      output.add(new Text(element.toString().toLowerCase()));
    }
    return output;
  }
}
```

And then invoke the UDF directly on the data:

```
hive> ADD JAR my_jar.jar;
Added my_jar.jar to class path
Added resource: my_jar.jar
hive> CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION lower_array AS 'my.package_name.LowerArray';
OK
Time taken: 2.803 seconds
hive> SELECT id, lower_array(data) FROM foo;
...
... Lots of MapReduce spam
...
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 2 seconds 760 msec
Ended Job = job_1422453239049_0015
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Job 0: Map: 1   Cumulative CPU: 2.76 sec   HDFS Read: 358 HDFS Write: 44 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 2 seconds 760 msec
OK  
1001        ["one","two","three"]
1002        ["four","five","six","seven"]
Time taken: 27.243 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

There are some trade-offs between the two approaches.  #2 will probably be more efficient at runtime in general than #1, since the `GROUP BY` clause in #1 forces a reduction stage while the UDF approach does not.  However, #1 does everything in HiveQL and is a bit more easily generalized (you can replace `lower` with some other kind of string transformation in the query if you needed to).  With the UDF approach of #2, you potentially have to write a new UDF for each different kind of transformation you want to apply.

Comment: I like it! Thanks much for all these details. I'll try to UDF way first as I'll learn some things on the way :)

Comment: Can the first approach be used to preserve the relative order of values when collecting?